# How do I create directory if none exists using File class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this statement:

```
File.open(some_path, 'w+') { |f| f.write(builder.to_html)  }
```

Where

```
some_path = "somedir/some_subdir/some-file.html"
```

What I want to happen is, if there is no directory called `somedir` or `some_subdir` or both in the path, I want it to automagically create it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can use FileUtils to recursively create parent directories, if they are not already present:

```
require 'fileutils'

dirname = File.dirname(some_path)
unless File.directory?(dirname)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(dirname)
end
```

**Edit: Here is a solution using the core libraries only (reimplementing the wheel, not recommended)**

```
dirname = File.dirname(some_path)
tokens = dirname.split(/[\/\\]/) # don't forget the backslash for Windows! And to escape both "\" and "/"

1.upto(tokens.size) do |n|
  dir = tokens[0...n]
  Dir.mkdir(dir) unless Dir.exist?(dir)
end
```

Comment: FileUtils **is** in the stdlib: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html

Comment: Oh ok. I meant the core, not the stdlib. Either way, that's fine. This works. Thanks!

Comment: I added a core-only solution to my answer: Be aware, however, that it essentially reimplements `FileUtils.mkdir_p` (which is the method dedicated to your use case)

Comment: Note that `FileUtils#mkdir_p` works even if the directory hierarchy already exists (it just does nothing) so this solution can be compressed into this can one-liner plus a require statement: `FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(some_path))`

Comment: @Eureka - I'm troubleshooting an issue where we get "Errno:EEXIST (File exists - foo)" when the directory already exists.  it is an older app - maybe the spec has changed.

Comment: @JosephK - for me this (misleading) EEXIST error ended up being a permission issue.

Comment: No need for a `File.directory?` check. The function will do nothing if the name already exists as a directory.

Answer (score 98):

For those looking for a way to **create a directory if it doesn't exist**, here's the simple solution:

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.mkdir_p 'dir_name'
```

Based on Eureka's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617152/how-do-i-create-directory-if-none-exists-using-file-class-in-ruby#comment17013487_12617369).

Comment: This is @Eureka's comment - "Note that FileUtils#mkdir_p works even if the directory hierarchy already exists (it just does nothing) so this solution can be compressed into this can one-liner plus a require statement: `FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(some_path))`"

Answer (score 27):

```
directory_name = "name"
Dir.mkdir(directory_name) unless File.exists?(directory_name)
```

Comment: You may run into race conditions using this method, the directory could get created after File.exists? runs but before Dir.mkdir is executed.

Answer (score 8):

How about using `Pathname`?

```
require 'pathname'
some_path = Pathname("somedir/some_subdir/some-file.html")
some_path.dirname.mkdir_p
some_path.write(builder.to_html)
```

Comment: It works with `some_path.dirname.mkpath` instead of `some_path.dirname.mkdir_p`

Comment: +1 on `mkpath`. Also if you just have the directory and not the path, there's no need for `dirname`, e.g. Pathname("somedir/some_subdir").mkpath will work the same way.

Answer (score 7):

Based on others answers, nothing happened (didn't work). There was no error, and no directory created.

Here's what I needed to do:

```
require 'fileutils'
response = FileUtils.mkdir_p('dir_name')
```

I needed to create a variable to catch the response that `FileUtils.mkdir_p('dir_name')` sends back... then everything worked like a charm!

Comment: doesn't make sense. why you need to catch the return?

Comment: @huanson , I didn't need to catch the return... but the logic didn't work until I created `response = FileUtils.mkdir_p('dir_name')`. If I didn't create this variable, `FileUtils.mkdir_p('dir_name')` wasn't working for me... or at least that's what I recall happened (this answer is more than 1 year old). I wouldn't be surprised if a newer version of Ruby fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Along similar lines (and depending on your structure), this is how we solved where to store screenshots:

In our env setup (env.rb)

```
screenshotfolder = "./screenshots/#{Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}"
unless File.directory?(screenshotfolder)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(screenshotfolder)
end
Before do
  @screenshotfolder = screenshotfolder
  ...
end
```

And in our hooks.rb

```
  screenshotName = "#{@screenshotfolder}/failed-#{scenario_object.title.gsub(/\s+/,"_")}-#{Time.new.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")}_screenshot.png";
  @browser.take_screenshot(screenshotName) if scenario.failed?

  embed(screenshotName, "image/png", "SCREENSHOT") if scenario.failed?
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer's "core library" only solution was incomplete. If you want to only use core libraries, use the following:

```
target_dir = ""

Dir.glob("/#{File.join("**", "path/to/parent_of_some_dir")}") do |folder|
  target_dir = "#{File.expand_path(folder)}/somedir/some_subdir/"
end

# Splits name into pieces
tokens = target_dir.split(/\//)

# Start at '/'
new_dir = '/'

# Iterate over array of directory names
1.upto(tokens.size - 1) do |n|

  # Builds directory path one folder at a time from top to bottom
  unless n == (tokens.size - 1)
    new_dir << "#{tokens[n].to_s}/" # All folders except innermost folder
  else
    new_dir << "#{tokens[n].to_s}" # Innermost folder
  end

  # Creates directory as long as it doesn't already exist
  Dir.mkdir(new_dir) unless Dir.exist?(new_dir)
end
```

I needed this solution because FileUtils' dependency gem rmagick prevented my Rails app from deploying on Amazon Web Services since rmagick depends on the package libmagickwand-dev (Ubuntu) / imagemagick (OSX) to work properly.